# cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function in ionic project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I get this error, when trying to run an ionic app on android with livereload.

```
cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function
```

When I try to re-install cordova, I get the same error. (`npm install -g ionic cordova`).

I removed the platform.

```
cordova platform rm android
```

and added it again:

```
cordova platform add android --save
```

All that changed nothing.

This is my ionic info output:

```
Ionic:
```

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.3.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v8.11.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 2.15.12
   OS                : Windows 10

Environment:

ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Android Studion is up 2 date...

How can I get rid of that error?

Many Thanks